# What does $ f ^ {n} (x ^ {1/n}) = ... $ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I was asked to check whether the sequence of functions $ \{ x_{n} (t) \} $ defined as

$$
x ^{n} _{n}(t ^ \frac{1}{n}) = \begin{cases}n, & t \leq \frac{1}{n} \\\frac{1}{n},& t > \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}
$$

converges on $ [0, 1] $.

However, I'm struggling to understand the meaning of $ x ^{n} _{n}(t ^ \frac{1}{n}) $. What does it mean? Is it possible to simplify it somehow?

Clarification: $ x^{n}_{n}(t) $ is the n-th power of $ x_n(t) $

Comment: The first confusion arises, perhaps from the notation $\;x\;$ to denote a function, to begin with. Though it is used sometimes, it is more usually used when parametrizing curves. Now, what can $\;x_n^n(t)\;$ mean? I can't tell. Thouhg perhaps the exponents and the index are $\;n\;$ but that doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Maybe $$f^k_n(x^y)=\begin{cases}k & \text{ for } \ x \leq y \\ 1/n & \text{ for } \ x > y \end{cases}$$ It certainly is confusing notation. It just looks like a sequence of functions that converges to zero everywhere except at zero.

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: Not an answer to my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual notation is that $f^0(y)=y$ and $f^{n+1}(y)=f(f^n(y))$. That is, $f^n(y)$ is the $n$-th iterate of $f$ applied to $y,$ and that $f(t)\cdot f(t)$ is written $f(x)^2.$ There are some customary exceptions to this, especially with trigonometric functions, where, for example $\cos^2 y$ means $(\cos y)^2$, probably because it appears so often and someone tired of writing so many brackets. In your Q it is not obvious whether $x^n_n(t^{1/n})$ refers the $n$-th power or the $n$-th iterate of the function $x_n$. You should ask your source for clarification.

I would also suggest substituting $t=u^n$ in the def'n to simplify the LHS.

Comment: Thanks. I believe $ x^{n}_{n}(t) $ is the n-th power of $ x_n(t) $